# flex/lex analyzer generator: DFA minimization

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

Does flex or lex perform DFA minimization?

If so then I have these questions:

1. what algorithm is used?
2. say, we have a specification as below

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%%
a printf("a\n");
b printf("b\n");
%%
```

This corresponds to regular expression `a|b` and the DFA construction can result in a DFA with 3 states that parses this expression (in JSON format):

```
{states: [0, 1, 2],
 moves: [
   {from: 0, char: 'a', to: 1},
   {from: 0, char: 'b', to: 2}
 ],
 start: 0,
 final: [1, 2]
}
```

While this DFA works well, and for each accepting state it invokes the needed action correctly, the Hopcroft's algorithm for DFA minimization will merge the two accepting states into one which will result in a DFA with two states. This can be a problem because then we will not know which action to invoke in the accepting state. How does flex or lex handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Flex does not minimize DFAs, and neither did the original lex. I can't speak for every possible lex implementation which exists.
2. The Hopcroft algorithm starts by partitioning the states into exactly two sets: accepting and non-accepting states. These sets are obviously distinct, and the rest of the algorithm proceeds by refining the partitions. Because of the fundamental property of the algorithm, only one of these partitions needs to be re-examined.

   In the case of lexical specifications, the accepting state also bears a action number, with the result that the set of accepting states cannot be considered homogeneous. Instead, the initial partition must be into `N+1` subsets, where `N` is the number of lexer actions. Unless there is only a single action, this will not be a binary refinement, so the fundamental property doesn't apply and all partitions need to be re-examined.

   Also, the classic Hopcroft algorithm assumes that the DFA is complete; every state has a transition on every input. That's not the case for (f)lex-generated DFAs. There are modifications to the algorithm which can deal with this issue, or you can just add a single sink state to the state set (all of whose out-transitions are circular).

Comment: Actually, (f)lex generated DFAs ARE complete -- any input string will generate some action, evn if just the default ECHO action for inputs that don't match any user-defined pattern.  Also, the main point of flex's state packing is to minimize the space required to store the state transition tables, not to minimize the number of states.   However, that state packing is a custom flex algorithm with little (if any) relation to the Hopcroft algorithm, so your basic points stand.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: that doesn't make the DFA complete; it just means that some prefix of every input will be accepted. If the flex scanner reaches a state in which there is no transition with the current input character, it backs up to the last-recorded accepting state. In a sense, that makes the effective machine complete, in that there is an action for every input, but the DFA as computed has missing transitions. The question was not about state packing, but about state *minimization* so I didn't get into state packing. The packing algorithm has absolutely no relation to Hopcroft minimization.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: the point about the missing sink state seems trivial, but it does require a modification to the Hopcroft algorithm, because that algorithm relies on being able to partition the full state set. It means that you cannot use the optimization of assuming that the initial partition is binary. But, then, you can't do that anyway, as I noted.

Comment: my point is that flex (and I assume other lex implementations -- flex is the only one I have much familiarity of the internals) *does* create that sink state, as its needed to properly support backtracking to find the correct match to emit, even if no user pattern matches.  The reason the Hopcroft algorithm is inapplicable is your point 2 -- needing the action number (and backtrack info) associated with the specific accepting state.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Maybe it's a semantic issue. Afaik, flex uses "jam transitions" to indicate that the transition for the incoming character is the last one to be taken. The target of the jam transition is technically a state number, but it is used only as an index into the action table since transitions from the target state can never be taken. A 0 in the action table indicates that a backup is needed, and there are typically quite a few of those. There is a straightforward process which can turn that into a complete DFA, but I'm not sure it can be done in all cases without inventing a new state...

Comment: ... Anyway, there is no problem adapting the Hopcroft algorithm to minimize states; it's only necessary to create an appropriate initial partition and refinement workqueue. I've done this by starting with the flex-generated tables, and it does reduce table size a bit, but I think that the original judgement that the gain is not worth the effort was probably valid. My implementation did invent a sink state, but perhaps that was unnecessary.